# Possible to natively create hidden file or directory using AS3 / AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Am I blindly missing a method for creating a hidden file or directory in an AIR / AS3 desktop app?  Re-combing the docs, all I see is the `File.isHidden` read-only property. I know I could do this via `NativeProcess` and native code, but I'm hoping to avoid creating native code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mac and Linux you only need to put a dot (".") in front of the file/folder name.

For Windows is a little bit more complicated since it is a property of the file. I've done it in the past by calling the "attrib" command, but yeah, you would need NativeProcess for that AFAIK.

Juan

Comment: Good call on the `.hidden`... I forget since I have my hidden folders visible :)  Thanks, man.